# Реализация шаблона производитель / потребитель

Tags: многопоточность, java

Привет всем, прошу помочь с проблемой.

И так... есть 3 производителей и 2 потребителей, все разные потоки и работают все одновременно. Есть очередь с 200 элементами. Производители добавляют случайное число от 1..100, а потребители берут эти числа. Если в очереди элементов >= 100 производители спят, если нет элементов в очереди - потребители спят. Если элементов стало <= 80 производители просипаются. Все это работает до тех пор пока пользователь не нажал на кнопку "q", после чего производители останавливаются а потребители берут все элементы, только потом программа завершается.

В моем коде последний поток так и попадает в `wait()` и программа виснет.

**SimpleDataQueue.java**

```
public class SimpleDataQueue {

    private int head;
    private int tail;
    private volatile int elementsCount;
    private Integer[] myArrayQueue;

    public SimpleDataQueue(int size) {
        myArrayQueue = new Integer[size];
    }

    public void add(Integer element) {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (elementsCount >= 100) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            myArrayQueue[head] = element;
            elementsCount++;

            if (head == myArrayQueue.length - 1) {
                head = 0;
            } else {
                head++;
            }
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public Integer remove() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (getElementsCount() == 0) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Integer value = myArrayQueue[tail];
            myArrayQueue[tail] = null;
            elementsCount--;

            if (tail == myArrayQueue.length - 1) {
                tail = 0;
            } else {
                tail++;
            }

            if (elementsCount <= 80) {
                notifyAll();
            }
            return value;
        }
    }

    public synchronized int getElementsCount() {
        return elementsCount;
    }
}
```

**Producer.java**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Producer implements Runnable{

    private SimpleDataQueue queue;
    private volatile boolean ready = false;

    public Producer(SimpleDataQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        while(!ready) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        queue.add(rand.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Queue elements size is: " + queue.getElementsCount());
        }
        System.out.println("                    Ending " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        ready = true;

    }
}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

        private volatile SimpleDataQueue queue;
        private volatile boolean ready = false;
    //  private SomeUtil someUtil;

        public Consumer(SimpleDataQueue queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
    //      someUtil = new SomeUtil();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Random rand = new Random();

            while(!(ready && (queue.getElementsCount() == 0))) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                queue.remove();
                System.out.println("Queue elements size is: " + queue.getElementsCount());
            }
            System.out.println("                    Ending " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }

        public void shutdown() {
            ready = true;

        }
    }
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        SimpleDataQueue queue = new SimpleDataQueue(200);
        Producer producer = new Producer(queue);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(producer);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(producer);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(producer);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(consumer);
        Thread t5 = new Thread(consumer);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        producer.shutdown();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();

        consumer.shutdown();

        t4.join();
        t5.join();

        System.out.println("Finish!");

    }
}
```

**Console.log**

```
Queue elements size is: 1
Queue elements size is: 0
Queue elements size is: 0
Queue elements size is: 0
Queue elements size is: 0
Queue elements size is: 0
Queue elements size is: 1
Queue elements size is: 2
Queue elements size is: 3
Queue elements size is: 4
Queue elements size is: 5
Queue elements size is: 4
Queue elements size is: 3
Queue elements size is: 4
Queue elements size is: 3
Queue elements size is: 2
Queue elements size is: 3
Queue elements size is: 4
Queue elements size is: 5
Queue elements size is: 6
Queue elements size is: 7
Queue elements size is: 6
Queue elements size is: 5
Queue elements size is: 4
Queue elements size is: 5
Queue elements size is: 4
Queue elements size is: 5
Queue elements size is: 6
Queue elements size is: 7
Queue elements size is: 8
Queue elements size is: 9
Queue elements size is: 8
Queue elements size is: 9
Queue elements size is: 10
Queue elements size is: 9
Queue elements size is: 10
Queue elements size is: 9
Queue elements size is: 8
Queue elements size is: 9
Queue elements size is: 8
Queue elements size is: 9
Queue elements size is: 8
Queue elements size is: 7
Queue elements size is: 8
Queue elements size is: 9
Queue elements size is: 10
Queue elements size is: 11
Queue elements size is: 12
Queue elements size is: 11
Queue elements size is: 12
Queue elements size is: 13
Queue elements size is: 14
                    Ending Thread-2
Queue elements size is: 13
Queue elements size is: 12
Queue elements size is: 13
                    Ending Thread-1
Queue elements size is: 12
Queue elements size is: 13
                    Ending Thread-0
Queue elements size is: 12
Queue elements size is: 11
Queue elements size is: 10
Queue elements size is: 9
Queue elements size is: 8
Queue elements size is: 7
Queue elements size is: 6
Queue elements size is: 5
Queue elements size is: 4
Queue elements size is: 3
Queue elements size is: 2
Queue elements size is: 1
Queue elements size is: 0
                    Ending Thread-3
```

Answer (score 2):

[[@seroj](/users/12868/seroj)](/users/12868/seroj), ничего удивительного. У Вас могут и все Consumer-ы повиснуть.

Смотрите, что получается. Consumer проверил ready и ушел в sleep(). В этот момент Вы сбрасываете ready, но спящий после sleep() этого не проверяет, и идет в remove() где навсегда зависает в wait(), поскольку все, кто мог бы вызвать notifyAll() уже завершились.

*Только тривиальная проверка ready после sleep() Вас не спасет* (гонки останутся, только виснуть будет реже... Итог понятен).

Вам нужна дополнительная операция с очередью - stopQueue(). Заведите еще один ready в классе SimpleDataQueue и сбрасывайте его при вызове stopQueue() (также синхронизированной и вызывающей notifyAll()).

Естественно в while-ах в add и remove этот ready надо проверять. Тут конечно возникает вечная Jav-овская морока с единственным возвращаемым значением (Вы после возврата из add-remove должны уметь **надежно** определять успешно ли выполнена операция).

Возможный вариант (совсем не в духе Java) это возврат признака через дополнительный аргумент add/remove (массив из одного элемента).

Кстати, если  интересно, то в "исследованиях" есть такая тема (на Си и C#), можете почитать.

Comment: ага, вот она: http://hashcode.ru/research/221526/

Comment: спасибо Вам всем. Кажется все получилось. Незнаю насколько все правильно с точки зрения ООП и многопоточности но надеюсь что мой код одобрят при интервю джюниоров. В Consumer.java добавил один if(после sleep() и перед queue.remove() );
if (queue.getElementsCount() > 0) {
queue.remove();
}

Comment: @seroj, все же учтите, что более правильно это специально "закрывать" очередь. Иметь в ней флаг on/off и действовать в соответствии с ним в методах queue.add() и queue.remove() (не забывая о notifyAll).

По крайней мере, имейте это ввиду на своем интервью.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант №2, проблема может быть в том что, потоки потребителей будут ждать товар, когда уже нет производителей, как вариант в класс очереди добваить булевую переменую - есть ли активные производители, и если их нет не ждать при попытке удалить из очереди а сразу возвращаться.

Comment: Интересно... Пока писал свой ответ, здесь все (вместе с комментариями) изменилось.

Comment: Не знаю на сколько это плохо, но когда понял что ответ неверный, удалил его вместе со всей веткой коментов,а потом написал еще один)